# Training Yolov4-Custom in Google Collab training.txt corrupted

Tags: python, deep-learning, yolo

i'm currently training japanese character with Yolov4-custom with AlexeyAB Darknet repository.

whenever, i tried to train these error occurs :

[image]

Then, i figured out what is the problem after tried to checking everywhere else that
when i checked on google-collab text viewer, The `train.txt` line is changing. Some of the line is changed or even the numbers is dwindling or even increasing each time i uploaded it again/copy this file to `darknet/obj/data`.

**This time it's Dwindling and also the last line is cut off by itself**

[image]

**This one is increased**

[image]

**this is supposed to be the real amounts of data i have and ended with this pat**h
`data\obj\9_タ-ta_61_train_.png`

[image]

**my command when trained the data :**

`!./darknet detector train data/obj.data yolov4-obj.cfg yolov4.conv.137 -map -dont_show`

Note : all of my datasets were placed on my github, so whenever i try to train at google-collab i must clone my repo and move every things to the correct place inside darknet folder, using this particular command :

```
%mv Japanese-Character-Classification-with-Yolov4/obj darknet/data/
%mv Japanese-Character-Classification-with-Yolov4/train.txt darknet/data/
%mv Japanese-Character-Classification-with-Yolov4/test.txt darknet/data/
%mv Japanese-Character-Classification-with-Yolov4/obj.names darknet/data/
%mv Japanese-Character-Classification-with-Yolov4/obj.data darknet/data/
%mv Japanese-Character-Classification-with-Yolov4/yolov4-obj.cfg darknet/
```

i also did double check before training is being run, the amounts of the path inside `train.txt` doesn't change whether i clone it from the git or moving the files, and the problem is persist when the training started.

i suspect that, maybe the encoding of Google-Collab linux was not UTF-8.
Please inform me if this kind of thread was ever posted, because i cant find any solution from google.

My Repo : https://github.com/Sekigahara/Japanese-Character-Classification-with-Yolov4

Answer (score -1):

i managed to fix this, it was misunderstand that the text editor in google collab actually appending every text if i try to open it twice or more. My mistakes were actually the `train.txt` and `test.txt` list of path was made from windows which using '\' or '\\', the ubuntu(google-collab) path slashes using the opposite one which '/'

[image]